# How to Retrieve cell value from jqgrid afterinsertrow function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid-php

Is that possible to retrieve the value from the `jqgrid afterinsertrow` function? I tried to alert the data but it displays `"undefined"`:

```
function(rowid,data){
   alert(data.Name); // "Name" is my column name
}
```

Comment: when i alert rowid it's working correctly..! Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The afterInsertRow executes only when the grid parameter **gridview** is false

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    gridview : false,
    afterInsertRow : function( rowid, rowdata, rawdata) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

By default this parameter is true

P.S Added example. 
Please [check this demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/support/afterinsrow/)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer but the example I created here http://jsfiddle.net/8dYNq/ could give you some idea.

You will get the data via `afterInsertRow` event args when initializing the `jqGrid`. But when + icon is clicked, it will insert a blank row. Hence field values are `undefined`. Please look at console log for details.

Comment: Please, post your full code or create a demo in jsfiddle.net in order to get help